# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 FUNCTION database.COLUMN_JSON does not exist

Tags: mysql, sql, json, laravel, mariadb

I've recently upgraded from Laravel 5.2 to 5.3 and now I'm trying to make my app working again. I'm getting this error that I didn't get before on 5.2, when trying to run this query:

```
SELECT COLUMN_JSON(item_items.attrib) as attrib FROM item_items, item_categories WHERE item_items.category_id=item_categories.id)
```

I'm using MariaDB 10.3 but this also happens on MySQL 5.7.
Any ideas what might cause it or how to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: The function exists in MariaDB 10.0.1 and later according to the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/dynamic-columns/#column_json), but it definitely does not exist in MySQL of any version. I suppose you are not testing with MariaDB as you think you are. You should verify by executing `SELECT @@version;`

Comment: @BillKarwin what would be the alternative for mysql? I'm thinking to migrate from mariadb to mysql since mariadb has brought me only problems...

Comment: Try the [JSON data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html). You don't need any function like COLUMN_JSON() to return that in JSON format.

Comment: Although I also encourage you not to use JSON at all in an SQL database. It's bound to cause more problems than it solves. You might like my presentation [How to Use JSON in MySQL Wrong](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-use-json-in-mysql-wrong)

Comment: Thanks for sharing, @BillKarwin! This is an old structure did by other devs and I am just trying to make it work while upgrading Laravel. I might move it completely to mysql.

Comment: Btw, I checked the version like you suggested... and it returns "10.3.14-MariaDB-1:10.3.14+maria~bionic"

Comment: Okay I have no clue about MariaDB. Never used it, never will.